# Disable querying collection in Firebase Cloud Firestore with rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore, and I want to modify my rules to restrict users from querying a collection.

This should not be allowed:

```
firestore().collection("users").get()
```

But this should be allowed:

```
firestore().collection("users").doc("someUserId").get()
```

Currently, my rules look like this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read;
}
```

but this rule allows the "users" collection to be queried.

How can I allow single document gets, but not collection queries?

Comment: I don't think you can write rules that only apply to collections. If you look at the [Firestore Security Rules Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure), you'll notice that all the security rules are being applied to documents and their subcollections. There's no rule specifying a condition to access a collection.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought while reading the documentation, but I wanted to see if someone knows a way...

Comment: Yeah it's quite unclear from the documentation - `list` rules apply to collections.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can break read rules into **get** and **list**. Rules for get apply to requests for single documents, and rules for list apply to queries and requests for collections ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#request_methods)).

```
match /users/{userId} {

  //signed in users can get individual documents
  allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;

  //no one can query the collection
  allow list: if false;
}
```

Comment: Another example in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#evaluating_constraints_on_queries

Comment: Btw, `allow list: if false;` has no effect here (the line is redundant). If you only allow `get`, list will be disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just allow `get` and you'll be good:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow get;
}
```

Reference: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#:~:text=Convenience%20methods-,read,-Any%20type%20of](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#:%7E:text=Convenience%20methods-,read,-Any%20type%20of)