# How to restrict read and write in one collection and restrict write in another collection both of which are related to same user in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have users and profiles collection in the cloud firestore as shown in the image below. I am storing user details in user collection with document ID as a firebase UID of the user so that only a particular user can update and read its own data and not other users. I have security rules for users collection something like in this answer [Disable querying collection in Firebase Cloud Firestore with rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659317/disable-querying-collection-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-with-rules)
Now my profile collection should be a public collection of documents such that these IDs can be referenced to read details of profiles but whenever user update their data in users collection it should also be reflected in the profile document if the common fields are updated. How can I achieve this?

P.S: In user document fields are like name, age, payment details and in profile it's like name and age only.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Functional Requirement:**

> Whenever user update their data in users collection it should also be
>   reflected in the profile document if the common fields are updated.

You can use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes), as follows:

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

var userId = '......';

var commonData = {
    name: '...',
    age: ...
}

var userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);
batch.update(userRef, {paymentDetails : "...", ...commonData});  
// We use the spread syntax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

var profileRef = db.collection('profiles').doc(userId);
batch.update(profileRef, commonData);

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

---

In terms of `write` security rules, you would define them as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow ....
    }

    match /profiles/{userId} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow ....
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: So, I read some posts and thought of using cloud functions whenever there is an update to user document, do you think it's a good idea thinking of cost and scalability?

Comment: Cloud Function is also a valid alternative. It really depends on your general application architecture. It is difficult, with the info you have shared to tell you what would be better. If, in your front-end, you have all the necessary data (`name`, `age`, `paymentDetails`, ...) a batched write is a very good option.

Comment: Yes, I have those details in front-end. I want to keep the document ID public, suppose these users make some comment on some post then their reference ID should be there to access their public profile from there.

Comment: That's somehow another question. You just need to save the user ID in the comment to the post. You would get the user id through `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`, see  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#get_the_currently_signed-in_user